# Create JSON string with php issue

Tags: php, json

I want to create a JSON with this structure:

```
{"id":"ws",
 "data":[
   {"name":"it.geosolutions"},
   {"name":"cite"},
   {"name":"testwor"},
   {"name":"tiger"},
   {"name":"sde"},
   {"name":"topp"},
   {"name":"newwork"},
   {"name":"sf"},
   {"name":"nurc"}
 ]
}
```

I do:

```
function funcArray(){
 foreach ($ws as $item){
  $wsarray[] = '{"name":"'.$item->name.'"}';
 }  
 return $wsarray;
}

$json_data = array ('id'=>'ws','data'=>funcArray());
$json = json_encode($json_data);
```

And i get:

```
{"id":"ws",
 "data":[
   "{\"name\":\"it.geosolutions\"}",
   "{\"name\":\"cite\"}",
   "{\"name\":\"testwor\"}",
   "{\"name\":\"tiger\"}",
   "{\"name\":\"sde\"}",
   "{\"name\":\"topp\"}",
   "{\"name\":\"newwork\"}",
   "{\"name\":\"sf\"}",
   "{\"name\":\"nurc\"}"
  ]
}
```

How to repair it?

**UPDATE**

I was tried this:

```
function funcArray(){
 foreach ($ws as $item){
   $wsarray[] = json_encode(array('name'=>$item->name));
 }  
 return $wsarray;
}
```

But get:

```
{"id":"ws","data":["{\"name\":\"it.geosolutions\"}","{\"name\":\"cite\"}","{\"name\":\"testwor\"}","{\"name\":\"tiger\"}","{\"name\":\"sde\"}","{\"name\":\"topp\"}","{\"name\":\"newwork\"}","{\"name\":\"sf\"}","{\"name\":\"nurc\"}"]}
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't build JSON this way. Use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on a PHP array instead.

```
$arr = array(
"id" => "ws",
"data" => array(
  array("name" => "it.geosolutions"),
  array("name" => "cite"),
  array("name" => "testwor"),
  array("name" => "tiger"),
  array("name" => "sde"),
  array("name" => "topp"),
  array("name" => "newwork"),
  array("name" => "sf"),
  array("name" => "nurc")
));

echo json_encode($arr);
```

---

Output

```
{"id":"ws","data":[{"name":"it.geosolutions"},{"name":"cite"},{"name":"testwor"},{"name":"tiger"},{"name":"sde"},{"name":"topp"},{"name":"newwork"},{"name":"sf"},{"name":"nurc"}]}
```

---

To work with your `$ws` array, you can probably do something like this:

```
echo json_data(array(
  "id" => "ws",
  "data" => array_map(function($item) { return array("name" => $item->name); }, $ws)
));
```

**Note** using [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) like this requires `>= PHP 5.3`

Comment: Clever use of `array_map`, +1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a array first then use json_encode to create json output. Dont hard code any json there..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of building the json string in the function `funcArray` why not build an array and return it

```
function funcArray(){
   foreach ($ws as $item){
       $wsarray[] = array("name"=>$item->name);
    }  
    return $wsarray;
  }

 $json_data = array ('id'=>'ws','data'=>funcArray());
 $json = json_encode($json_data);
```